# Firefox does not show table headers in print popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, printing

I have a page with print button which prints a table. Now in Chrome or IE it works fine but in Firefox it does not show the table headers. Here are some screenshots of Chrome and Firefox.

In Firefox:

[image: In Firefox]

In Chrome:

[image: In Chrome]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome's default styling might be different from FireFox's,

Have you tried using a [`print query`](https://benfrain.com/create-print-styles-using-css3-media-queries/) in your CSS?

```
@media print {
  table, table thead, table th {
    display: block !important /* or any other desired display value */;
  }
}
```

Good luck.

Comment: It worked for the first table only , later when there are multiple tables in one page it only shows the first one's header.

Comment: Try using `display: block !important`.

Comment: @adnan_aust did it work? If so don't forget to mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome auto sets the print page setting. for chrome sometimes you have to manually set the headers and footers.
Try the following:

In the print preview window, make sure Scale is set to Shrink To Fit.

Make sure the Portrait orientation is set.

Click Page Setup.... The Page Setup window will appear.

In the Page Setup window, click the Margins & Header/Footer tab.

In the Margins section, make sure the page margins are set correctly (the default setting is 12.7 mm, or 0.5 in).

You're good to go!